# Form isn't posting data into MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

Trying to get this form to add new data into my database yet for some reason it doesn't seem to work? Instead of staying on the same page "admin.php?page=3" it redirects to just "admin.php" and no echos or signs that it is even doing anything? Could someone help me out here? Cheers!

Form:

```
<form>
<form name="postnewstory" action="admin.php?page=3" method="POST">
<strong>News Title: </strong><input type="text" name="news_title"><br><br />
<strong>News Story:</strong><br>
<textarea name="news_body" rows="4" cols="60"></textarea><br><br />

<input type="file" name="news_photo"><br>
<strong>Story Link: </strong><br />
<input name="button" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked">No Link<br>
<input type="radio" name="button" value="1">Link<br><br />
<strong>Link Address: </strong><input type="text" name="news_link"><br>
<strong>News Story Tags: </strong><input type="text" name="news_tags">    
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="postnewstory" class="btn btn-success"><br />
</form>
```

PHP:
I know its very basic, just trying to get it to work before I add error checks or anything.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['postnewstory'])){
    $username = $user_data['username'];
    $email_address = $user_data['email_address'];
    $news_title = $_POST['news_title'];
    $news_photo = $_POST['news_photo'];
    $button = $_POST['button'];
    $news_link = $_POST['news_link'];
    $news_tags = $_POST['news_tags'];

$exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die ("not found");
    if (mysql_num_rows($exists) != 0){
        //update the info in database
        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO news (`news_id` ,`news_title` ,`news_body` ,`news_photo` ,`news_date` ,`username` ,`news_tags` ,`button ,`news_link`)
        VALUES (NULL , '$news_title', '$news_body', '$news_photo', now(), '$username', '$news_tags', '$button', '$news_link');") or die ("update didn't work");

        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>This post was sent!</strong></span></div> ";
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=admin.php?page=3">';
} else echo "<strong><font color=red>Update did not work, please try again.</font></strong>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Isn't that how it's meant to be?

Comment: Just took that out, now it's staying on the same page but saying "update didn't work"

Comment: Replace `die ("update didn't work");` with `die (mysql_error());` to know the exact error why your query ain't working.

Comment: *Um...* what is `$user_data`? I think you want to change both of those to `$_POST` --- As it stands, it's a stray variable. @AidanPT which is most likely the reason why your code is not working and you might need to add a few hidden fields for them instead.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'news_link`) VALUES ('trhrth', '', '', now(), '', 'rthrthrt', '0', 'trhrth')' at line 1

Comment: Thats what the error says, and $user_data gets the logged in users username

Comment: See my answer below @AidanPT missing backtick for `button`

Comment: +1 - I quoted you buddy @ShankarDamodaran - You're a star ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing backtick in:

```
,`button
```

change to:

```
,`button`
```

Rewrite:

```
("INSERT INTO news (`news_id` ,`news_title` ,`news_body` ,`news_photo` ,`news_date` ,`username` ,`news_tags` ,`button`,`news_link`)
```

---

**Footnotes:**

I quote [`Shankar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510008/form-isnt-posting-data-into-mysql-database#comment34248811_22510008):

*"Replace `die ("update didn't work");` with `die (mysql_error());` to know the exact error why your query ain't working."*

Comment: It's amazing how much of a problem the little details can cause. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, even a missing dot, comma etc. can ruin someone's day. Glad to have been able to help and found a solution for you, cheers @AidanPT amazing how much power a simple character has, eh?

Comment: :) Nah not needed mate @Fred-ii- **+1** for solving the issue

Comment: It's always best and useful information @ShankarDamodaran and thank you :)

Comment: Shankar's a *star*, yet he's so "modest" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work;
Change the line

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=admin.php?page=3">';
```

to

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'admin.php?page=3';</script>";
```

Comment: It's now staying on the same page but saying "update did not work" think there might be something wrong with the INSERT ?

Comment: As said by @Shankar, replace die ("update didn't work"); with die (mysql_error());.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'news_link`) VALUES ('trhrth', '', '', now(), '', 'rthrthrt', '0', 'trhrth')' at line 1

Comment: Replace `button with \`button\`